# Is there a way to open a .zprj file in Blender?

Tags: file-format

None of the Blender's importation options can take care of the .Zprj file that I have downloaded, as it is never displayed in the file browser.

How do you proceed to open such files ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think .zprj file is a specific file for marvelous designer, as you cant open for example maya .ma because it means to be for maya only. So no, you have to open it in marvelous designer and covert it into other universal format as OBJ or STL

Comment: @Fowl would you make an answer out of that to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.zprj file is a specific file for marvelous designer, as you cant open for example maya .ma because it means to be for maya only. So no, you have to open it in marvelous designer and covert it into other universal format as OBJ or STL